# Ncurses not able to display colors on terminal window

Tags: c++, terminal, ncurses

Ncurses is not able to display colors on my terminal window.

Some useful questions that you might ask:

Q. Did I see my terminal display any colors before?

> A. Yes, I installed "Oh-my-zsh" and during the install, I could see the colors.

Q. What is the value of your "$TERM"?

> A. xterm256-color

Q. What did Ncurses returned for "has_colors()" and "can_change_colors()"?

> A. For both, it returned "true".

Q. Did I change anything while installing Ncurses?

> A. Nothing, I just issued "sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev".

Q. What language are you coding it in?

> A. C++

Q. What is the OS?

> A. Ubuntu 20.04 running in WSL. I also tested the code on online VMs and the output remained the same.

Q. What is the program?

> A. Here's the code:

```cpp
#include "curses.h"
int main() {
    initscr();
    start_color();
    use_default_colors();  // doesn't really matter, because I removed it but the output was the same
    init_pair(1,COLOR_RED,COLOR_BLACK);
    attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    printw("Hello World");
    attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Q. What I am linking against?

> A. Linking flag: "-lncurses"

Q. What is the compiler?

> A. g++ version = 9.3.0

Q. What is the version of Ncurses?

> A. 6.2.0 (i.e latest)

Q. What are the colors that it is displaying?

> A. Normal terminal colors (i.e Black and White)

If you want any additional information, I can provide that in the comments.

Comment: Q: What is the question you ask from us?

Comment: For what it's worth as a data point, the code worked for me `/usr/bin/clang++ -pedantic -Weverything -Wextra-semi-stmt -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-padded -Wno-poison-system-directories -fsanitize=undefined,null,address,bounds,bool,enum -std=c++17 GhostVaibhav.cpp -lcurses` (I have a `xterm-256color`, but using bash on x86_64-apple-darwin20, not zsh in Ubuntu 20.04 running in WSL.)

Comment: @ÖöTiib How can I enable Ncurses to display colors?

Comment: @Eljay Cool bro, any ideas to get it working on my machine?

Comment: We do not know why the colors are missing on your machine. The colors of some kind of terminal with some kind of ncurses work on your machine. So perhaps you have some kind of ncurses and or terminal that do not display colors or are configured not to display colors compiled and linked. Try to find something that uses ncurses and where colors work after you build it. Then figure out where is difference.

Comment: My first thought to try:  can you just use ANSI escape sequences directly and get colors?  Second thought:  how did `TERM` get set to `xterm256-color` (maybe that is messed up)?

Comment: @Eljay I didn't know about `TERM` before so I don't know when it was set to that value. But giving it a second thought, I think that it came by default.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I will try that out

Comment: @ÖöTiib I solved the problem. I was mistakenly using the PDCurses header file on UNIX platforms which is not supported. I fixed it by using the Ncurses header file. Thanks for all the help!